# (mutex) lock for callback function C++

Tags: c++, callback

In a multi-threaded application, `mutex::lock` is used to prevent two threads accessing the same memory location at the same time. In my application, I do not use multiple threads but I have a **callback function** that writes to a vector and a loop in the main function, that reads it. Sometimes, I get this error:

> Vector iterator + offset out of range

After checking the vector in debugging, all seems to be fine: the number of elements is right and none of the elements in invalid. Is there a similar possibility for callback functions?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Mutexes are irrelevant for this case. Your out-of-range exception has nothing to do with concurrent access; it's just a logical error in your code. Find and fix that error, using your debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any concurrent calls to your callback function, there's no need for a `std::mutex`.

> Is there a similar possibility for callback functions?

No, a callback function is called in sequential order, if there aren't any concurrent threads.

If you have out of range errors, use the debugger and check the index values used to access the vector elements.

Comment: Sequential order with respect to what? It follows as a sequence to what, exactly?